# Metapost rotating labels around their center rather than the origin

Tags: diagrams, geometry, draw, metapost

Currently I am trying to to rotate some labels so that they match the orientation of lines in a diagram.

For example like this:
[image]

The problem with that example is that the label was rotated around the origin, rather than it's own axis, which moves it from the position it should be. This is the same diagram without rotating the label:

[image]

As you can see, the position of the label is actually in the middle of the segment. Normally to rotate the way I want you first rotate and then translate, but I haven;t been able to apply the rotation to the label before moving it.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[border=6cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{mplibcode}
u:=2cm;

vardef line(expr pfirst, psecond)=
    m := 0.07;
    pair tangent, normal, off, ofs, osf, oss, pointOne, pointTwo;
    tangent := psecond - pfirst;
    tx := xpart tangent;
    ty := ypart tangent;
    numeric len;
    len = sqrt(tx*tx + ty*ty);
    tangent := tangent * 1/len;
    normal := tangent rotated 90;

    pointOne := pfirst + tangent * 0.2;
    pointTwo := psecond - tangent * 0.2;

    off := pointOne - normal * m;
    ofs := pointTwo - normal * m;
    draw u*off--u*ofs withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor black;
    draw u*off--u*(off + (normal * 0.15 rotated 240)) withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor black;   

    osf := pointOne + normal * m;
    oss := pointTwo + normal * m;
    draw u*(osf)--u*(oss) withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor black;   
    draw u*oss--u*(oss + normal * 0.15 rotated 60) withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor black;  
enddef;

input latexmp;
% Start figure
beginfig(0);


pair vzero, vone, vtwo, vthree;  
vzero := (0, 1);
vone := (0, -1);
vtwo := (-2, 0);
vthree := (2, 0);

line(vzero, vone);
line(vzero, vtwo);
line(vtwo, vone);

line(vone, vthree);
line(vthree, vzero);
line(vone, vthree);


vzero := u*vzero;
vone := u*vone;
vtwo := u*vtwo;
vthree := u*vthree;
fill fullcircle scaled 8bp shifted vzero;
fill fullcircle scaled 8bp shifted vone;
fill fullcircle scaled 8bp shifted vtwo;
fill fullcircle scaled 8bp shifted vthree;

label.top("\huge$v_0$", vzero + (0, 0.2) * u);
label.bot("\huge$v_1$", vone + (0,-0.2) * u);
label("\huge$v_2$", vtwo + (-0.4, 0) * u);
label("\huge$v_3$", vthree + (0.4, 0) * u);

label("\huge$p_2f_1$", (vzero + vtwo) * 0.5);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\par}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
label("\huge$p_2f_1$", (vzero + vtwo) * 0.5);
```

you can use this:

```
labeloffset := 7bp; % necessary here to avoid overlapping the arrows
draw thelabel.top("\huge$p_2f_1$", .5[vzero,vtwo]) rotatedaround (.5[vzero,vtwo], angle(vzero-vtwo));
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing that lots you might like to make a macro:

```
vardef label_along(expr your_label, target_path, time_on_path, offset) = 
    draw thelabel(your_label, origin) rotated angle direction time_on_path of target_path
        shifted (up scaled offset rotated angle direction time_on_path of target_path)
        shifted point time_on_path of target_path 
enddef;
```

Here's a version of your diagram that uses it.

[image]

And the source for that:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
vardef label_along(expr your_label, target_path, time_on_path, offset) = 
    draw thelabel(your_label, origin) rotated angle direction time_on_path of target_path
        shifted (up scaled offset rotated angle direction time_on_path of target_path)
        shifted point time_on_path of target_path 
enddef;

vardef connect(expr a, b) = 
    save arc, barb, alpha;
    path arc, barb; 
    arc = a -- b cutbefore fullcircle scaled 8 shifted a
                  cutafter fullcircle scaled 8 shifted b;
    numeric alpha;
    alpha = angle (b-a);
    barb = (arc -- (right scaled ahlength 
                          rotated (alpha + 180 - 1/2 ahangle) 
                          shifted point 1 of arc))
           shifted (up scaled 1 rotated alpha);
    draw barb; draw barb rotatedabout(1/2[a,b], 180);
enddef;

beginfig(1);

    z0 = -z1 = 42 up;
    z3 = -z2 = 68 right;

    dotlabel.top("$v_0$", z0);
    dotlabel.bot("$v_1$", z1);
    dotlabel.lft("$v_2$", z2);
    dotlabel.rt("$v_3$", z3);

    connect(z0, z1);
    connect(z0, z2);
    connect(z0, z3);
    connect(z1, z2);
    connect(z1, z3);

    label_along("$p_2 f_1$", z2--z0, 0.4, 8);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex`.

- The key thing about rotations in this sort of work is to `rotate` the object before you `shift` it.  Or use `rotatedabout`...
- `ahangle` and `ahlength` are the plain MP parameters used for regular arrow heads.